springboot3.2.4 + thymeleaf +AdminLTE ,why css notfound?
this is resources file directory

this is login.html  

<link rel="stylesheet" th:href="@{/plugins/fontawesome-free/css/all.min.css}">
<!-- icheck bootstrap -->
<link rel="stylesheet" th:href="@{/plugins/icheck-bootstrap/icheck-bootstrap.min.css}">
<!-- Theme style -->
<link rel="stylesheet" th:href="@{/dist/css/adminlte.min.css}">

console show

I don't know what went wrong,please help me

The best way of incorporating AdminLTE with Spring Boot is the following:

Add AdminLTE webjar using Maven/Gradle (whatever you're using)



<dependency>
    <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
    <artifactId>AdminLTE</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.0</version>
</dependency>




Set up MVC configuration for accessing resources from webjars.

@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class MvcConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/static/**")
                .addResourceLocations("classpath:/static/");

        registry
                .addResourceHandler("/templates/**")
                .addResourceLocations("classpath:/templates/");

        // Add WebJars for AdminLTE
        registry.addResourceHandler("/adminlte/**")
                .addResourceLocations("classpath:/META-INF/resources/webjars/AdminLTE/3.2.0/")
                .setCacheControl(CacheControl.maxAge(30, TimeUnit.DAYS));
    }
}


Access AdminLTE stuffs from your html template page by using proper path beginning with /adminlte prefix.



<!-- Add CSS as follows -->
  
<link rel="stylesheet" th:href="@{/adminlte/plugins/fontawesome-free/css/all.min.css}">
<link rel="stylesheet" th:href="@{/adminlte/plugins/icheck-bootstrap/icheck-bootstrap.min.css}">
<link rel="stylesheet" th:href="@{/adminlte/dist/css/adminlte.min.css}">

<!-- Add script as follows -->

<!-- jQuery -->
<script th:src="@{/adminlte/plugins/jquery/jquery.min.js}"></script>
<!-- Bootstrap 4 -->
<script th:src="@{/adminlte/plugins/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js}"></script>
<!-- AdminLTE App -->
<script th:src="@{/adminlte/dist/js/adminlte.min.js}"></script>




Finally, whitelist /adminlte/** endpoint in your security config.

